# Completeness in the Noncommutative Geometry "Dictionary"

Tags: operator-algebras, complete-spaces, noncommutative-geometry

In numerous references on noncommutative geometry, one can find some sort of "dictionary" for translating concepts on the topological/geometric side into their corresponding algebraic counterparts (and vice versa). Here is one such example from [*Elements of Noncommutative Geometry*](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780817641245):

[image]

> My question is: what exactly is the role played by completeness on the topological side? The algebraic side is described in terms of a $C^\ast$-algebra, which is complete in the norm topology by definition, but what happens if we have something like a $C^\ast$-algebra less completeness?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be a bit confused here. The dictionary goes between spaces (on the left) and algebras (on the right). $C^*$-algebras live on the right side while completeness is a property of the space and so it would live on the left side. So in this respect the completeness of the $C^*$-algebra doesn't come in to play. In fact, since completeness is not a topological property (it is a uniform property) it doesn't fit nicely into the left-hand side either.

For example, $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic and thus have isomorphic corresponding $C^*$-algebras while one is complete and the other is not.

Finally, you're question seems to also be getting at the question of what can we do with non-complete algebras.

While I'm not an expert in non-commutative geometry, as far I know one often looks at dense subalgebras of $C^*$-algebras, which are non complete. The motivation here is that when one puts additonal structure on the topological space (like for example a smooth structure) you want the collection of functions to preserve this structure (so look at smooth functions and not all continuous functions). This amount to looking at a subset of the original $C^*$-algebra and thus restricting attention to the dense sub-algebra described above.

Comment: Although I appreciate the comments following it, I beg to differ with the first paragraph (though I very well could be, to no fault of your own, just failing to understand what you're saying). The definition of a C*-algebra (the right side) consists of being a Banach algebra (with additional structure, of course), which are required to be both normed and complete in the norm topology. The completeness I am referring to is precisely that completeness. If something in the very definition of the right side is not a property on the right side, I don't know what is. :P

Comment: But, as you said, I am getting at what we can do with non-complete algebras. Perhaps a way to say what I'm getting at is... if you take, say, the Gelfand-Naimark theorem and replace the category of commutative (focusing on commutative ones for simplicity) $C^\ast$-algebras (and proper ${}^\ast$-morphisms) by a category of algebras that have all the same properties of $C^\ast$-algebras, but are not necessarily complete in the norm topology (if such a collection even defines sensible objects for a category...), then what category of topological spaces ...

Comment: ... if any, would one need to maintain their (anti)equivalence? Perhaps there is no clear answer to such a question, but that's more along the lines of what I'm asking. Or, perhaps to give some more specific questions along these lines... if one takes one of these (commutative) $C^\ast$ minus complete algebras $\mathcal{C}$... will the Gelfand spectrum (the space of characters on $\mathcal{A}$ still be... for example.... Hausdorff? Will the Gelfand topology even still be a topology? (etc.)